# When using GetPosition for ArrayAdapter, Object with Equal Fields Return UnEqual

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have created a dropdown in Android Xamarin from which I would like to auto select a dropdown value on page load. When the page is launched, it is passed a MyClass object with a Num value of 52. My dropdown has been passed an ArrayAdapter which has a list of MyClass objects, one of which has a Num value of 52. When I try to `mySpinner.SetSelection(recommendedPosition);` it is not working because `myClassAdapter.GetPosition(recommendedValue)` returns -1

I thought that the example in the following article (which shows me how to override the Equals and Hash functions of MyClass) would help me, but it still results in -1 being returned. It seems that these overridden functions are not being hit when I place a breakpoint on them.. but I understood that the GetPosition method calls IndexOf which should result in my overriden functions being called.
https://www.javaworld.com/article/3305792/comparing-java-objects-with-equals-and-hashcode.html

In this example, MyClass has one field of Num.. but my code has many more properties in MyClass, all of which are equal between recommendedValue and one of the items in listMyClass.

In InstantiateItem of my ViewPager I call:

```
var recommendedValue = new MyClass("52");
var List<MyClass> listMyClass = new List<MyClass> { new MyClass("52"), new MyClass("46") };

mySpinner = view.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.mySpinner);
var myClassAdapter = new MyClassAdapter(view.Context, listMyClass);
mySpinner.Adapter = myClassAdapter;

//*
// I need the following to not return -1
//*
var recommendedPosition = myClassAdapter.GetPosition((MyClass)recommendedValue);
```

MyClass.cs

```
public class MyClass: Java.Lang.Object
{
    private string Num { get; set; } = "";

    public MyClass() {}

    public MyClass(int? num)
    {
        Num = String.IsNullOrEmpty(num) ? "" : num;
    }

    public string GetNum()
    {
        return Num;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return Equals(other as MyClass);
    }

    public bool Equals(MyClass otherItem)
    {
        if (otherItem == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return otherItem.Num == Num;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 19;
        hash = hash * 31 + (Num == null ? 0 : Num.GetHashCode());
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Comment: could it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could consider not using `GetPosition` method,you could directly get the position like this :

```
var recommendedValue = new MyClass("52");
var List<MyClass> listMyClass = new List<MyClass> { new MyClass("52"), new MyClass("46") };
var recommendedPosition = listMyClass.IndexOf(recommendedValue);
```

or you could define a `GetSelectPosition(MyClass myClass)` in your `MyClassAdapter` :

```
class MyClassAdapter: ArrayAdapter<MyClass >
{
    public Context context;
    public List<MyClass> list;

       ...

    public int GetSelectPosition(MyClass myClass)
    {
        return list.IndexOf(myClass);
    }
}
```

then you could call like ：

```
var recommendedPosition = myClassAdapter.GetSelectPosition(recommendedValue);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just be reimplementing their GetPosition function?

Comment: @SweetTomato `GetPosition` internally depends upon [List#indexOf(T)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) and which relies on equals method,as you have got the List<MyClass>,you could directly use it.and the GetSelectPosition method is only encapsulates a method in your adapter according your List<MyClass>.it is not reimplementing their GetPosition function.

Comment: Thank you. I implemented your solution and it is working. I am still curious why GetPosition was not using my overridden Equals methods when it runs IndexOf inside of GetPosition. Maybe it doesn't know what class the object it is running GetPosition on is? Therefore is using the base Equals methods and not my overrides.